# MSSQL PHP Query 200+ Server Databases

Tags: php, sql-server

I am running PHP v5.3.22 on IIS7. I have a query that I need to run against **220** remote server MSSQL databases. Worked great until I hit the 30s timeout limit. I have excluded the servers with the slowest connections and that gets me a few more results.

I loop through: Connect to server, query, echo results (6 to 12 records), disconnect, onto next server, repeat.

I have adjusted and found that

```
ini_set( "max_execution_time", 60)
```

seems to be the most consistent that does not throw a 500 error.

What else can I check? Or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: simple: don't run this script under a webserver. That timeout exists for a reason. For this type of thing, you should be running the scan as a separate script (e.g. `system('scan.php &')` and then periodically check on the scan's progress. Command-line PHP is not subject to the timeouts by default.

Comment: In addition to comments by @MarcB above, you may also want to consider some level of parallelization in executing this work.  You can fork multiple processes and get through this work much faster (obviously you will have constraints on system resources you have available to run parallel processes).

Comment: Exapanding on what @MarcB said, set up a scheduled task to pull this data every so often and populate a local table. Now, your users can query the data instantly. Make sure to provide a `Data last updated: DATETIME` note so that people understand that it isn't real-time data